# how to set checkbox in bottomright side corner of imageview in each cell of gridview

Tags: android, gridview

### When User Select number of images from Gridview using Checkbox and click on Submit Button then add all the selected items and display those in another activity.

```
    public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override your `ImageAdapter`'s `getView()` method.

Create a separate layout for your GridView items. Put your ImageView and CheckBox in this layout. Little code snippet below. It's not full, you can complete it ;)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```